Android deep linking is working in mobiles but not in tablets
I just started the Android development.
I'm working on the Android deep linking now and it works fine in phones but not in tablets.
This is my AndroidManifest.xml.
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity,RedundantLabel">
    
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:host="mysite.com" android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="mysite.com" android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="www.mysite.com" android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="www.mysite.com" android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

What could be the potential problems? and How to solve this problem?

What "tablets" are you talking about. Please name example model names and their Android version, the same for the working phone models.
